# collecting images from website in python 2.7

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm not geting actually why is the syntax error here on line 17:

```
parsed[2] = image["src"]
```

then on line 18 :

```
outpath = os.path.join(out_folder, filename)
```

then 19 also:

```
urlretrieve(urlparse.urlunparse(parsed), outpath)
```

Answer (score 0):

This :

```
filename = image["src".spilit("/")[-1]
```

Should be :

```
filename = image["src"].split("/")[-1]  ## spell corrected and square bracket added.
```

Comment: done with syntax error now showing this error: 
 if _name_ == "_main_":
NameError: name '_name_' is not defined

Comment: error: 
if name == "main": 
NameError: name 'name' is not defined

Comment: `if __name__ == '__main__':`  . note double underscore.

Comment: thnx now this one is coming:

url = sys.argv[-2]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: while running code using "python <filename.py>" u need to pass argument . like "python <filename.py> <targetfolder> <url>" . <url> is address from which u want to get images. and <targetfolder> is location where images will store.

Comment: u need to debug. use `print` .

Answer (score 0):

you make some syntax error,
at line 17 you have to close the bracket

```
filename = image["src".spilit("/")[-1]
```

should be

```
filename = image["src"].spilit("/")[-1]
```

at line 20 you should put colon(:) at end

```
if image["src"].lower().startswith("http")
```

should be

```
if image["src"].lower().startswith("http"):
```

at line 21 why you put colon at end of statement? (remove colon)
at line 26, this is indentation error, you have to indent properly

at line 29, use single colon and close main keyword

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

i think you run your script like:

```
python filename.py
```

you should provide extra command line argument like:

```
python filename.py extraarg
```

Comment: done with syntax error now showing this error: if name == "main": NameError: name 'name' is not defined –

Comment: done now showing this 

url = sys.argv[-2]
IndexError: list index out of range